# Pass data back to caller from the template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I wish to have a template render some data which needs to be passed back to the caller of `render`. For example, I am using a template to generate emails, for which I need a subject as well as the body. I would like to do something like this:

```
app.render( 'email', function(err,html) {
  subject = ?get from template somehow?
  postEmail( subject, html, user_addr );
});
```

That is, I wish for the template to decide what should appear in the subject (preferably without creating another template just for the subject line).

Comment: I don't think this will be possible. You have to create a modified version of `jade` and look into the render implementation of express.

Comment: Or parse the rendered template. If it's HTML, that won't be too hard to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you figured this out yet, but you can send back information from Jade by altering the value of the arguments.

email.jade:

```
- subject.text = "Hi " + user + ", welcome to the site.";
| Subject: #{subject.text}
```

app.js:

```
args = { user: 'Test User', subject: { text: '' } };
app.render( 'email', args, function(err,html) {
  subject = args.subject.text;
  postEmail( subject, html, user_addr );
});
```

It has to be a nested object (i.e. `subject.text` instead of simply `subject`), otherwise you won't get the modified data. Although, if you call templates created with `jade.compile()` directly, then the nesting appears to be unnecessary. I think express must make a shallow copy of the arguments before sending it to the view engine.

Comment: I figured the OP wanted to get the rendered result back, passing vars back and forth between Express and Jade doesn't seem to make much sense to me :)

Comment: @robertklep It might make sense if you're rendering the same template from multiple points in your code, or the name of the template is a variable where lots of templates might follow the same pattern, but produce different results.

Comment: okay, good point :) it's not something I would do (probably), but it could make sense. Btw, +1 because of figuring out how to get data back from Jade.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks. For the record, I probably wouldn't do this either. I certainly wouldn't advocate for this paradigm if you can avoid it, but it directly addressed the question in this case.

Comment: This should work. I'm using a different solution now, but I'll try this one in the future.

Comment: @robertklep, I do want the rendered result, but I also want a subject. Keeping it with the template seems like a desirable solution.